# OOP paradigm implementation of a Dictionary data model

Tags: java, linked-list, generics, hash-map

Here is the implementation of `interface Dictionary` using chained hash table `class HashTableChained`.

Despite item 22* saying

> Favour static member classes over non static

in *Effective Java*, I used non static member class `DListNode` in `class DblyLinkList`, because any instance of the `DListNode` class MUST be associated with an instance of the `DblyLinkList` class. `class DListNode` is not for the users of `class DblyLinkList`.

`class Entry` could have been top level class, without any code change in `class HashTableChained`. The reason is that `class Entry` is introduced as a `static` member class because it avoids breaking encapsulation.

**DblyLinkList.java**

```
package JavaCollections.list;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * Dlist using sentinel node
 * 
 * @author mohet01
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class DblyLinkList<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    /*
     * Representation - starts
     */
    /**
     * DListNode is a node in a DblyLinkList
     * 
     * @author mohet01
     *
     */
    private class DListNode {

        /**
         * item references the item stored in the current node. prev references
         * the previous node in the DList. next references the next node in the
         * DList.
         *
         * Compiler transformation adds access code for private members
         *
         */

        private T item; 
        private DListNode prev;
        private DListNode next;

        DListNode(T item, DListNode p, DListNode n) {
            this.item = item;
            this.prev = p;
            this.next = n;
        }

    }

    private class Itr implements Iterator<T> {

        private DListNode currentPosition = sentinel;

        private int lastRet = -1;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentPosition.next != sentinel;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (currentPosition.next == sentinel) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            T nextItem = currentPosition.next.item;
            lastRet = +1;
            currentPosition = currentPosition.next; // points to the node that
                                                    // is already read
            return nextItem;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() throws NoSuchElementException {
            if (lastRet < 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            } else {
                // this item is already read using next()
                currentPosition.item = null;
                currentPosition.prev.next = currentPosition.next;
                currentPosition.next.prev = currentPosition.prev;
                currentPosition = currentPosition.prev;
                lastRet = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * sentinel references the sentinel node.
     *
     * Being sentinel as part of implementation detail, will avoid null checks,
     * while performing mutable operations on list.
     * 
     * DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING FIELD DECLARATIONS.
     * 
     */
    protected DListNode sentinel;
    protected int size;

    /**
     * newNode() calls the DListNode constructor. Use this class to allocate new
     * DListNodes rather than calling the DListNode constructor directly. That
     * way, only this method needs to be overridden if a subclass of DList wants
     * to use a different kind of node.
     * 
     * @param item
     *            the item to store in the node.
     * @param prev
     *            the node previous to this node.
     * @param next
     *            the node following this node.
     */
    DListNode newNode(T item, DListNode prev, DListNode next) {
        return new DListNode(item, prev, next);
    }

    /*
     * Representation - ends
     * 
     * DblyLinkList invariants: 1) sentinel != null. 2) For any DListNode x in a
     * DblyLinkList, x.next != null. 3) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList,
     * x.prev != null. 4) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList, if x.next == y,
     * then y.prev == x. 5) For any DListNode x in a DblyLinkList, if x.prev ==
     * y, then y.next == x. 6) size is the number of DListNode's, NOT COUNTING
     * the sentinel (referenced by "sentinel"), that can be accessed from the
     * sentinel by a sequence of "next" references.
     */

    /*
     * User Interface - starts
     */
    /**
     * DblyLinkList() constructor for an empty DblyLinkList.
     */
    public DblyLinkList() {
        this.sentinel = this.newNode(null, this.sentinel, this.sentinel);
    }

    /**
     * Return the size of the linked list
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void remove(int index) throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (index > size()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        DListNode node;
        for (node = sentinel; index-- > 0; node = node.next)
            ;
        node.item = null;
        node.prev.next = node.next;
        node.next.prev = node.prev;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a non-sentinel node at front of the list.
     * 
     * @param item
     */

    public void insertFront(T item) {

        DListNode node = this.newNode(item, this.sentinel, this.sentinel.next);
        node.next.prev = node;
        sentinel.next = node;
        this.size++;
    }

    /**
     * insertBack() inserts an item at the back of this DList.
     * 
     * @param item
     *            is the item to be inserted. Performance: runs in O(1) time.
     */
    public void insertBack(T item) {
        DListNode node = this.newNode(item, this.sentinel.prev, this.sentinel);
        this.sentinel.prev = node;
        node.prev.next = node;
        this.size++;
    }




    /**
     * Remove first non-sentinel node from the list. Do not require size check
     * before remove operation
     * 
     */
    public void removeFront() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (this.size() < 0) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("removeFront");
        } else {
            sentinel.next.next.prev = sentinel;
            sentinel.next = sentinel.next.next;
            this.size--;
        }
    }

    public T get(int index) throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (index > size())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        DListNode node;
        for (node = sentinel; index-- > 0; node = node.next)
            ;
        return node.item;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }

}
```

**Dictionary.java**

```
package cs61b.homework6.dict;

/**
 * An interface for (unordered) dictionary ADTs.
 *
 * DO NOT CHANGE THIS FILE.
 **/

public interface Dictionary<K, V> {

    /**
     * Returns the number of entries stored in the dictionary. Entries with the
     * same key (or even the same key and value) each still count as a separate
     * entry.
     * 
     * @return number of entries in the dictionary.
     **/

    public int size();

    /**
     * Tests if the dictionary is empty.
     *
     * @return true if the dictionary has no entries; false otherwise.
     **/

    public boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     *  A class for dictionary entries.
     *
     *  DO NOT CHANGE THIS FILE.  It is part of the interface of the
     *  Dictionary ADT.
     **/

    class Entry<K, V> { // class within interface is automatically 'public static'.

        protected K key;
        protected V value;

        public K key() {
            return key;
        }

        public V value() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create a new Entry object referencing the input key and associated value,
     * and insert the entry into the dictionary. Return a reference to the new
     * entry. Multiple entries with the same key (or even the same key and
     * value) can coexist in the dictionary.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the key by which the entry can be retrieved.
     * @param value
     *            an arbitrary object.
     * @return an entry containing the key and value.
     **/

    public Entry<K, V> insert(K key, V value);

    /**
     * Search for an entry with the specified key. If such an entry is found,
     * return it; otherwise return null. If several entries have the specified
     * key, choose one arbitrarily and return it.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the search key.
     * @return an entry containing the key and an associated value, or null if
     *         no entry contains the specified key.
     **/

    public Entry<K, V> find(K key);

    /**
     * Remove an entry with the specified key. If such an entry is found, remove
     * it from the table and return it; otherwise return null. If several
     * entries have the specified key, choose one arbitrarily, then remove and
     * return it.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the search key.
     * @return an entry containing the key and an associated value, or null if
     *         no entry contains the specified key.
     */

    public Entry<K, V> remove(K key);

    /**
     * Remove all entries from the dictionary.
     */

    public void makeEmpty();

}
```

**HashTableChained.java**

```
package cs61b.homework6.dict;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import JavaCollections.list.DblyLinkList;

/**
 * HashTableChained implements a Dictionary as a hash table with chaining. All
 * objects used as keys must have a valid hashCode() method, which is used to
 * determine which bucket of the hash table an entry is stored in. Each object's
 * hashCode() is presumed to return an int between Integer.MIN_VALUE and
 * Integer.MAX_VALUE. The HashTableChained class implements only the compression
 * function, which maps the hash code to a bucket in the table's range.
 *
 **/

public class HashTableChained<K, V> implements Dictionary<K, V> {

    /**
     * Place any data fields here.
     **/

    private long tableSize;
    private ArrayList<DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>>> defTable;

    /**
     * Construct a new empty hash table intended to hold roughly sizeEstimate
     * entries. (The precise number of buckets is up to you, but we recommend
     * you use a prime number, and shoot for a load factor between 0.5 and 1.)
     **/

    public HashTableChained(long sizeEstimate) {

        if (!(isPrime(sizeEstimate) && (sizeEstimate > 0L))) {
            sizeEstimate = nextPrime(sizeEstimate);
        }

        tableSize = sizeEstimate;
        defTable = new ArrayList<DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>>>((int) sizeEstimate);

        for (int i = 0; i < (int) sizeEstimate; i++) {
            defTable.add(i, new DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>>());
        }

    }


    /**
     * Construct a new empty hash table with a default size. Say, a prime in the
     * neighborhood of 100.
     **/

    public HashTableChained() {
        tableSize = 101;
        defTable = new ArrayList<DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>>>((int) tableSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            defTable.add(i, new DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>>());
        }
    }


    /**
     * isPrime() helper function
     * @param n
     * @return
     */
    private static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        if (n < 2)
            return false;
        if (n == 2 || n == 3)
            return true;
        if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
            return false;
        long sqrtN = (long) Math.sqrt(n) + 1;
        for (long i = 6L; i <= sqrtN; i += 6) {
            if (n % (i - 1) == 0 || n % (i + 1) == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * nextPrime() helper function
     * @param previous
     * @return
     */
    private static long nextPrime(long previous) {
          if (previous < 2L) { return 2L; }
          if (previous == 2L) { return 3L; }
          long next = 0L;
          int increment = 0;
          switch ((int)(previous % 6L)) {
            case 0: next = previous + 1L; increment = 4; break;
            case 1: next = previous + 4L; increment = 2; break;
            case 2: next = previous + 3L; increment = 2; break;
            case 3: next = previous + 2L; increment = 2; break;
            case 4: next = previous + 1L; increment = 2; break;
            case 5: next = previous + 2L; increment = 4; break;
          }
          while (!isPrime(next)) {
            next += increment;
            increment = 6 - increment;   // 2, 4 alternating
          }
          return next;
        }


    /**
     * Converts a hash code in the range Integer.MIN_VALUE...Integer.MAX_VALUE
     * to a value in the range 0...(size of hash table) - 1.
     *
     * This function should have package protection (so we can test it), and
     * should be used by insert, find, and remove.
     **/

    int compFunction(int code) {
        return code % (int) tableSize;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of entries stored in the dictionary. Entries with the
     * same key (or even the same key and value) each still count as a separate
     * entry.
     * 
     * @return number of entries in the dictionary.
     **/

    public int size() {
        int totalCount = 0;

        for(int index = 0; index < this.tableSize; index++){
            DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>> keyValueList = defTable.get(index);
            if(keyValueList.size() > 0){
                totalCount += keyValueList.size();
            }
        }

        return totalCount;
    }

    /**
     * Tests if the dictionary is empty.
     *
     * @return true if the dictionary has no entries; false otherwise.
     **/

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        for(int index = 0; index < this.tableSize; index++){
            DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>> keyValueList = defTable.get(index);
            if(keyValueList.size() > 0){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Create a new Entry object referencing the input key and associated value,
     * and insert the entry into the dictionary. Return a reference to the new
     * entry. Multiple entries with the same key (or even the same key and
     * value) can coexist in the dictionary.
     *
     * This method should run in O(1) time if the number of collisions is small.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the key by which the entry can be retrieved.
     * @param value
     *            an arbitrary object.
     * @return an entry containing the key and value.
     **/

    public Entry<K, V> insert(K key, V value) {

        Entry<K, V> entry = new Entry<K, V>();
        entry.key = key;
        entry.value = value;

        DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>> keyValueList = defTable.get(compFunction(key
                .hashCode()));
        keyValueList.insertBack(entry);
        return entry;
    }

    /**
     * Search for an entry with the specified key. If such an entry is found,
     * return it; otherwise return null. If several entries have the specified
     * key, choose one arbitrarily and return it.
     *
     * This method should run in O(1) time if the number of collisions is small.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the search key.
     * @return an entry containing the key and an associated value, or null if
     *         no entry contains the specified key.
     **/

    public Entry<K, V> find(K key) {

        DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>> keyValueList = defTable.get(compFunction(key
                .hashCode()));

        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> itr = keyValueList.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K, V> element = itr.next();
            if (element.key().equals(key)){
                return element;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Remove an entry with the specified key. If such an entry is found, remove
     * it from the table and return it; otherwise return null. If several
     * entries have the specified key, choose one arbitrarily, then remove and
     * return it.
     *
     * This method should run in O(1) time if the number of collisions is small.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the search key.
     * @return an entry containing the key and an associated value, or null if
     *         no entry contains the specified key.
     */

    public Entry<K, V> remove(K key) {

        DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>> keyValueList = defTable.get(compFunction(key
                .hashCode()));

        Iterator<Entry<K, V>> itr = keyValueList.iterator();
        Entry<K, V> element = null;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            element = itr.next();
            if (element.key().equals(key)){
                itr.remove();
            }
        }

        return element;
    }

    /**
     * Remove all entries from the dictionary.
     */
    public void makeEmpty() {
        for(int index = 0; index < this.tableSize; index++){

            DblyLinkList<Entry<K, V>> keyValueList = defTable.get(index);
            if(keyValueList.size() > 0){
                Iterator<Entry<K, V>> itr = keyValueList.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    itr.next();
                    itr.remove();
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

My understanding is that this is called a dictionary because every `DListNode` is *key-value* pair unlike normal chained hash-table where every `DListNode` is *value*(only).

Before using generics:

```
Dictionary dict = new HashTableChained();
dict.insert("word", new Integer(42));
Object count = dict.find("word"); // gives an Object, not an Integer
// need to cast - annoying, not safe
Integer countAsInteger = (Integer)count;
```

After using generics:

```
Dictionary<String, Integer> dict = new HashTableChained<>();
dict.insert("word", new Integer(42));
Integer count = dict.find("word"); // gives an Integer
```

The generic typing also protects you from creating a heterogeneous map. These are the reasons for introducing generic typing.

Are these classes following proper abstraction and encapsulation?

Answer (score 2):

**`Dictionary:`**

In Java, there is [**`java.util.Map`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface that is a key/value dictionary; use it.

**`defTable`:**

Let \$n\$ be the initial capacity of the table. Then you spend \$\Theta(n)\$ time initialising all first \$n\$ collision chains to empty linked lists. I understand that this is necessary due to the fact you use an `ArrayList`, but perhaps more idiomatic approach would be to implement a static inner class for entries:

```
private static class DictionaryNode<K, V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    DictionaryNode<K, V> previous;
    DictionaryNode<K, V> next;
    int keyHashCode; // You could also cache the hash code of the key.
                     // This way, when searching a collision chain in
                     // order to find whether it contains a given key,
                     // all entries with different hash codes cannot be
                     // the target key.
}
```

And then manipulate them in your actual **`HashTableChained`**.

**`size:`**

I suggest you add a field **`size`** to your **`HashTableChained`** and increment it whenever adding a new key/value-pair, and decrementing whenever removing a key/value-pair. After all, updating **`size`** takes only constant time, yet allows **`size()`** and **`isEmpty()`** run in \$O(1)\$ as well.

**`makeEmpty:`**
It makes sense to add operation **`clear()`** to **`DblyLinkList`**, which can be made to run in constant time (however, not counting garbage collection overhead). That way, **`makeEmpty()`** will run faster, as everything that is needed at each table component is calling that very \$O(1)\$ **`clear`** at each of them.